# How POCO (de)serialization works in protobuf-net?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Is it possible to (de)serialize a POCO type using neither protobuf-net attributes nor explicitly adding types into the model?

Comment: Note: if the issue is *protobuf-net* attributes, you can also use `[DataContract]/[DataMember(Order=n)]` or `[XmlType]`/`[XmlElement(Order=n)]` - and avoid a reference in your DTO layer.

Comment: I know that already. I was just curious about a completely POCO case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment - in short, no. It needs to have a *basic* understanding of how you intend it to operate. I guess maybe I could add something to let you *specify* a default strategy for completely unadorned types (things that aren't `DataContract`, `ProtoContract` or `XmlType`), but the most appropriate option there would be "all public members" (much like `XmlSerializer`).

The reason I don't want to encourage this is that it is brittle. Because of how the protobuf spec is defined, all you get is field-numbers. It is easy enough to say "ok, order them alphabetically and use their positions", but that is not safe if you ever want to change the type. And let's face it, we all do. You'd be amazed how often I add an `AardvarkCount` property, which messes with alphabetical orderings.

Hence, I don't want to make it easy to get people into a position where they risk data integrity. Because I don't like people shouting at me. If there was a global default policy, it would be easy to use that policy *without realising it*, which is when you start getting into trouble.

I do, however, intend making it easier to choose those strategies on a per-type basis (the code all exists, it just isn't in the public API) - for example:

```
model.Add(typeof(MyCrazyType), false).ApplyPolicy(ImplicitFields.AllPublic);
```

(the `ImplicitFields` stuff already exists, back to v1 days) or maybe just:

```
model.Add(typeof(MyCrazyType), ImplicitFields.AllPublic);
```

any help? does the reasoning make sense?

Comment: Absolutely. I agree with you, that implicit stuff is dangerous.

Comment: Will the ApplyPolicy be available soon?

Comment: I have a current need for the 'brittle' serialization mentioned above - I have an Event Sourcing system and would like to take snapshots of the in-memory object model. If the binaries change, I want to rebuild via the Event Log rather than the snapshot. Will this be possible with Proto-buf at some point? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. What integer id's would it use for the properties?

You could of course write some reflection based code that adds the types to the model without manually specifying the configuration. But I imagine you'll get versioning problems when you add/remove properties from your types. Since I see no way to create a stable mapping from strings to integers implicitly.

You probably could also define some key-value format inside protobuf so you can use string keys instead of integer keys. But then you lose the advantages protobuf offers. And you could just use json/bson instead.

Answer (score 0):

What CodesInChaos is saying is true, about model changes likely breaking things, but for simpler projects or where models are stable, you can do that effectively. Here's how: https://github.com/danielcrenna/protobuf-poco