# Is protobuf-net suited for serializing arbitrary object/domain models?

Tags: serialization, domain-driven-design, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, ddd-repositories

I have been exploring the CQRS/DDD-principles and patterns for a while now and have started implementing a sample project where I have split my storage-model into a WriteModel and a ReadModel. The WriteModel will use a simple NoSQL-like database where aggregates are stored in a key-value style, with value being just a serialized version of the aggregate.

I am now looking at ProtoBuf-Net for serializing and deserializing my domain model aggregates in and out of storage. [Other than this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212075/how-poco-deserialization-works-in-protobuf-net) I haven't found any guidance or tips for using ProtoBuf-Net in this area. The point is that the (ideal) requirements for serialization and deserialization of aggregates is that the domain model should have as little knowledge as possible about this infrastructural concern, which implies the following:

1. No attributes on the classes
2. No constructors, getters, setters or any other piece of code just for the sake of serialization.
3. Ability to use any (custom) type possible and have it serialized/deserialized.

Thus far I have implemented just the serialization of the first versions of my aggregates which works perfectly fine. I use the `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`-instance to configure the MetaModel at runtime and have `UseConstructor = false` everywhere, which enables me to completely separate the serialization mechanics from my domain-assembly. I have even implemented a custom post-deserialization mechanism that enables me to just-in-time initialize fields after ProtoBuf-Net has deserialized it into a valid instance. So suppose I have class AggregateA like so:

```
[Version(1)]
public sealed class AggregateA
{
    private readonly int _x;
    private readonly string _y;

    ...
}
```

Then in my serialization-library I have code something along the following lines:

```
var metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(AggregateA), false);
metaType.UseConstructor = false;
metaType.AddField(1, "_x");
metaType.AddField(2, "_y");
...
```

However, I realize that up to this point I have only implemented the basic scenario, and I am now starting to think about how to approach versioning of my model. I am particularly interested in larger refactoring-scenario's, where type A has been split into type A1 and A2, for example:

```
[Version(2)]
public sealed class AggregateA1
{
    private readonly int _x;

    ...
}

[Version(2)]
public sealed class AggregateA2
{
    private readonly string _y;

    ...
}
```

Suppose I have a serialized bunch of instances of AggregateA, but now my domain model knows only AggregateA1 and AggregateA2, how would you handle this scenario with ProtoBuf-Net?

A second question deals with point 3: is ProtoBuf-Net capable of handling arbitrary types if you're willing to put in some extra configuration-effort? I've read about exceptions raised when using the `DateTimeOffset`-type, which makes me think not all types can be serialized by the framework out-of-the-box, but can I serialize these types by  registering them in the RuntimeTypeModel? Should I even *want* to go there? Or better to forget about serializing common .NET types other than the simple ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protobuf-net is *intended* to work with predictable known models. It is true that everything can be configured at runtime, but I have not put any thought as to how to handle your `A1`/`A2` scenario, precisely because *that is not a supported scenario* (in my defense, I can't see that working nicely with most serializers). Thinking off the top of my head, if you have the configuration/mapping data somewhere, then you could simply deserialize twice; i.e. as long as we still tell it that `AggregateA1._x` maps to `1` and `AggregateA2._y` maps to `2`, you can do:

```
object a1 = model.Deserialize(source, null, typeof(AggregateA1));
source.Position = 0; // rewind
object a2 = model.Deserialize(source, null, typeof(AggregateA2));
```

However, more complex tweaks would require additional thought.

Re "arbitrary types"... define "arbitrary" ;p In particular, there is support for "surrogate" types which can be useful for some transformations - but without a very specific "problem statement" it is hard to answer completely.

Summary:

protobuf-net has an intended usage, which includes both serialization-aware (attributed, etc) and non-aware scenarios (runtime configuration, etc) - but it also works for a range of more bespoke scenarios (letting you drop to the raw reader/writer API if you want to). It does not *and cannot* guarantee to be a direct fit for every serialization scenario imaginable, and how well it behaves will depend on how far from that scenario you are.

Comment: Concerning the A1 / A2-scenario: yes, you may assume that x and y  from the old class will now directly map to A1.x and A2.y, so deserializing twice is actually what you need anyway (thanks for showing how to do that). What I mean by arbitrary is 'just any type you feed it', as long as you have registered it with the TypeModel. For example, I sometimes use the Lazy<T>-class inside my domain model. Can protobuf-net serialize this one just by doing 'RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Lazy<X>), false)'?

Comment: @Wim.van.Gool "just by" is perhaps misleading - you might need to tell it what you want serialized, etc. And it reserves a few inbuilt types; but in *general* you can do that, sure